# How could a UIVIew know its child has committed suicide

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a quick question:

View Controller X has added a sub-view: View Controller Y.

Y has a "quit" button. When the button is tapped, it removes its view from X's view hierarchy.

But I found Y's 'viewDidUnload' method is not called and its memory can't be released. How could Y release itself properly, or how could X know that Y is gone?

I believe I can make a protocol and let Y call a method from X, but I hope there is a easier way.

Comment: It sounds like View Controller Y could be presented modally - if it's an information box or dialog of some sort. Is this a possible solution for your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the Y view controller to get cleaned when its view is closed?
Prior to iOS5 there's nothing fancy to support more than one UIViewController on screen at once, so you basically how to make the calls yourself.
You could notify X when Y is closed (you could use NSNotificationCenter, or a delegate), and X would set Y's view to nil which would cause the viewDidUnload method to be called in it.
Additionally you could even release the Y view controller, which would dealloc every instance it has (along with the view itself) if you're not going to show it again.

Answer (score 0):

As you have added View Controller Y in View Controller X by coding...

```
    [viewX.view addSubView:viewY.view];
```

So, the viewDidLoad method wont going to execute. And, as far as memory management is concerns, you can code for that in viewX.m, i.e. as the "quit" has been tapped...

```
    [viewY removeFromSuperView];
    [viewY released];
```

Comment: X & Y are view controllers. I call [X.view addSubView:Y.view], in this case, Y's viewDidLoad actually gets called. The thing is I can't get the viewDidUnload from working.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know when a subview has been removed from its parent view, implement `didAddSubview:` and/or `willRemoveSubview:`. ([See here in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_3))

If you want to release the viewController when removing the view, you need to... release the viewController when you remove the view: `[viewController.view removeFromSuperview]; [viewController release]; viewController = nil;`

The `viewDidUnload` method is only called when there is a memoryWarning being issued by iOS, and that the ViewController then automatically unload its view (if it is not onscreen, e.g. the ViewController is not the topmost of a NavCtrl's stack so its view is not visible) to release some memory (and will then re-load the view from your XIB and recall `viewDidLoad` when it needs to reload the view to display it again).

Comment: thanks! I understand if I allocate memory in viewDidLoad, I should release it in viewDidUnload. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And you need to set your IBOutlets properties to nil too, so that you avoid using it by mistake while their corresponding UI items have been released. _(Of course these IBOutlets will automatically be rebound to the UI items when the view will be reloaded from the XIB again)_

Comment: Note also that managing memory warning is necessary but can become tricky for some use cases: e.g. imagine that you have as UITextView in your UI, you may need to keep its text in an NSString variable on viewDidUnload so that you can restore it on viewDidLoad, in case the user started entering text, the pushed a VC atop of your VC, the you receive a memWarning which makes your UITextView being released, so when you come back you need to restore the text in the UITextView that has been recreated!

Answer (score 0):

You should not have 2 UIViewControllers on screen at the same time.  There is a whole range of problems associated with that and it is not how they are intended to be used.

A single UIViewController should manage all subviews associated with a single screen.  If you want a "child" view subclass UIView and add it as a subview.

To allow to switch between view controllers easily, add a UINavigationController as the root view controller, and push/pop view controllers via that.  You can then change screens very easily.  Remember - you can turn of the navbar and/or animation you get no visual indication that your app is using a navigation controller, but full benefit of it's ability to manage a stack of views and ensure all the correct notifications are sent to each view controller as it loads/appears/disappears/unloads.

If you get in the habit of building every app with a UINavigationController as the root view controller things become very simple.